# \begin and \end in file hooks causing errors

Tags: hooks, filehook

With my package `jwjournal`, the whole document is put into an environment named `jwjournal` which does some regex replacement to the text. However, if the text is input via `\input` or `\include`, then the file content will not be processed by the environment. As a temporary way fix to this, it is possible to stop this environment before the `\input` and restart this environment afterwards, and the content of the subfile has to be put between `\begin{jwjournal}` and `\end{jwjournal}`.

Since I don't want the user to be bothered with this internal environment, I would like to do this automatically via the file hooks. Thus I wrote the following code:

```
\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument/end } { jwjournal }
  {
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { file/before } { jwjournal }
      {
        \begin{jwjournal}
      }
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { file/after } { jwjournal }
      {
        \end{jwjournal}
      }
  }
```

However, this doesn't do the work but rather produce the error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \environment jwjournal .
<inserted text>
```

How should I achieve this properly?

---

Below is a document for testing.

(`main.tex`)

```
\documentclass[12pt, color entry]{jwjournal}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \InputJournal { m }
  {
    \end{jwjournal}
    \input{#1}
    \begin{jwjournal}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \IncludeJournal { m }
  {
    \end{jwjournal}
    \include{#1}
    \begin{jwjournal}
  }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument/end } { jwjournal }
  {
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { file/before } { jwjournal }
      {
        \begin{jwjournal}
      }
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { file/after } { jwjournal }
      {
        \end{jwjournal}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\InputJournal{Entrys/2023/01}

\end{document}
```

(`./Entrys/2023/01.tex`)

```
2023-01-01
==========

Some text
```

Desired output should be like:

[image]

Comment: The `jwjournal` environment has a `+b`  arg spec: it's doing verbatim-like collection of material that needs `\end{jwjournal}` to appear at the end of the material. This therefore simply can't work ...

Comment: rather than stopping and starting the environment don't you want to use the file hook to apply whatever processing you need to the file content as well as the top level file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually putting the file content inside a `jwjournal` environment is what I would like to do, but as Joseph pointed out, this doesn't seem to be possible :(

Comment: yes but why do you need an environemnt can't you just directly appy your code to the file content and stop at end of file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I see. I think you are right, and I shall give it a try tomorrow! It is too late for me now...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your hint! By defining a new command using essentially the same code as the previous environment, and by using `\file_get:nnN` to get the file content into a macro instead of using `\input` and file hooks, I have succeeded in achieving the desired feature :)

Comment: glad you got it working, you could post a self answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, like me, you are using `b`-type argument in your environment to grab its content, then to make the functionality to work with `\input` or `\include` type command, you may do the following things:

1. Define a corresponding command version of your environment (later referred as `\YourCommandVersionOfTheEnvironment`). This is easy since in the definition of your environment you should have already been using `#1`.
2. Instead of using `\input` or `\include` with file hooks to add the `\begin` and `\end` of your environment (which would cause errors similar to the one stated in my question), you may define something like:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \MyInput { m }
  {
    \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
    \exp_args:No \YourCommandVersionOfTheEnvironment { \l_tmpa_tl }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \MyInclude { m }
  {
    \clearpage
    \MyInput { #1 }
    \clearpage
  }
```

This way you may successfully apply your processing to the file content.